# R : XLConnect POI API Array Ptg error

Tags: java, r, excel, apache-poi

Facing a wierd error while reading some cells of a `.xlsx` file using XLConnect package in R. `XLConnect` uses apache's `POI API` to do this function. Based on my limited reading on web, realising that some features are not allowed through this API. 
Currently I get this error,

> Error when trying to evaluate cell G5 - Unexpected ptg class (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.ArrayPtg)

Traced back-forth multiple times, being a complex sheet, not able to pin down to the culprit. Already spent hours on this but still unable. Anyone faced similar situation earlier?

There are hundreds of `vlookup`, `if()` etc in this file and tracing back each has not helped me yet.

One approach I followed was : 
1. I paste-by-value certain columns so that they independent of formula's and then run it, then no error occurs, which means this column is the culprit. However, as soon as I start splitting the cells in this column and follow the same strategy like in binary search, then it leads to nothing.

Any specific `Excel`'s formula that I should look into ?

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using under the covers? And what's the formula in problematic cell `G5` ?

Comment: @Gagravarr : `XLConnect` is using `Apache POI 3.16`. As I mentioned earlier is a long walk back. Though G5 is a simple sum of cells, each of those cells refer to something else which goes to something else and so forth. But it has a lot of `VLOOKUP`  in it. I'm assuming that it's the culprit though I am not sure. I can't share the excel sheet due to client confidentiality